# adding nonflow html tag to a advance custom field checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

Hello I want to add nofolow HTML tag to a Advance Custom Field checkbox, I means by cchecking the checkbox nofolow HTML tag lik will apear. Any suggest[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwuES.png)ion?

I want to add a custom field name nofolow, that field type would be checkbox. By clicking checkbox there will require  the link to have HTML tag nofolow.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox is a normal boolean, you could use something like:

```
$nofollow = get_field('nofollow');

<a href="#" rel="<?php echo esc_attr( $nofollow ? 'nofollow' : '' ); ?>">Click Me</a>
```